# Настройки сайта в laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5, laravel-5.6, фреймворк

как сделать контроллер доступным везде как например Auth
чтобы я например настройки сайта из таблицы settings мог вызвать в любом месте сайта?

Comment: `Auth` это фасад, не контроллер, почитайте доку.

Answer (score 0):

Да, Auth это и правда фасад. 
Можешь сделать модель Settings и дописать кастомный метод к ней.
Или юзай готовое 
https://github.com/anlutro/laravel-settings

Или сделай своё на основе готового.